# Access nested Object from JSON response in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am learning retrofit. The following is my json response:

```
 {
  "battingStyle": "Right-hand bat",
  "born": "April 24, 1973, Bombay (now Mumbai), Maharashtra",
  "bowlingStyle": "Right-arm offbreak, Legbreak googly",
  "country": "India",
  "creditsLeft": 248,
  "currentAge": "44 years 186 days",
  "data": {
    "batting": {
      "tests": {
        "50": "68",
        "100": "51",
        "4s": "",
        "6s": "69",
        "Ave": "53.78",      
      }
    }
  },

  "playingRole": "Top-order batsman",

}
```

I am trying to assign the values of "tests" section to  `Tests` POJO class.
But all the fields are being initialized to null.Where am I going wrong?

Code for my Interface:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("playerStats")
    Call<PlayerData> getPlayerData(@Query("apikey")String apikey, @Query("pid") String pid);
```

Code inside my `MainActivity`

```
  ApiInterface apiInterface = r.create(ApiInterface.class);
  Call<ODIs>call=apiInterface.getODIStats("apikey","pid");
  call.enqueue(new Callback<MatchData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PlayerData> call, Response<PlayerData> response) {
            try {
                  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(newGson().toJson(response.body()));

                s=jsonObject.toString();
                Tests tests = new Gson().fromJson(s, Tests.class);

            }
          catch (Exception e){}
```

Here, `r`is `Retrofit` instance.I am sorry if my code is redundant.I just started learning . Please let me know if I have to provide additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through each level, in this case first `data` object then `batting` object and finally `tests` object.

```java
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(newGson().toJson(response.body()));
JSONObject testsObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("batting").getJSONObject("tests");

Tests tests = new Gson().fromJson(testsObj.toString(), Tests.class);
```

Note that in order for it to work you have to use the `SerializedName` annotation to mark each field's name in the JSON, because it's not possible to have variable names start with a number:

```java
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Tests{
    @SerializedName("50")
    private String fifteen;

    @SerializedName("100")
    private String hundred;

    @SerializedName("4s")
    private String fourS;

    @SerializedName("6s")
    private String sixS;

    private String Ave;
}
```